# How to use a TypeScript definition file for another function

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm new to TS and would like to use a definition file I created to tell a separate function about it's arguments type.

functions.ts

```
export default ({}) => {
  const myFunction = ({ param1 }: { param1: string }) => {
    return param1;
  };

  return {
    myFunction
  };
};
```

functions.d.ts

```
declare var _default: ({}: {}) => {
    myFunction: ({ param1 }: {
        param1: string;
    }) => string;
};
export default _default;
```

someotherfile.ts

```
export default ({ functions }) => {
  functions().myFunction({ param1: 1 });
};
```

The `functions` parameter is from functions.ts above, but of course someotherfile.ts does not know what the structure of `functions` is.

How can I use functions.d.ts here?
Do I even need to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will solve your problem, just create a new type if you need only it.

```
// functionsType.ts
export type functions = ({}: {}) => {
  myFunction: ({ param1 }: {
      param1: string;
  }) => string;
};
```

and use it like so

```
//someotherfile.ts
import { functions } from './functionsType';

export default (functions: functions) => {
  functions({}).myFunction({ param1: 1 });
};
```

here is [stackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-oxfgmq) example where you can see an error about wrong argument type

Comment: An import path cannot end with a '.d.ts' extension. Consider importing './functions' instead.ts(2691). However you did give me the idea of adding typeRoots to my tsconfig.json file...

Comment: yeah but my import paths don't end with `.ts` or `d.ts`, I just mentioned with comments which import is equivalent to files in your example

Comment: Gotcha, but how can I import functionsTypes?

Comment: actually you can create just a new type, I updated my answer, and here is stackBlitz example https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-oxfgmq

Answer (score 0):

It does not work like that.

You use definitions to provide types to **untyped javascript** code you may import. For instance, let's say you did import library `X` into yout project and it did not have a `@types/X` package. Then you could write a `.d.ts` file to integrate it into your project. But that is completely optional, you can also consume JS code as-is, without types.

If you want the return of a function to depend on its arguments, what you are probably looking for is **generics**, which may be a somewhat complicated topic. For instance:

```
const myFunction = <Input extends { param1: any }>(inp: Input) => {
    return inp.param1
};
```

On the previous excerpt we tell that myFunction accepts *any object that at least has a property named param1*. And its return value will be inferred to whatever type param1 has. Which is different from writing:

```
const myFunction = (inp: { param1: any, [k: string]: any }) => {
    return inp.param1
};
```

This last example puts similar constraints on the function inputs, but the return type will be always erased to `any`.

The difference is that, while in the 2nd sample we are "casting" the input type, on the 1st sample, we are generically using whichever type comes in while imposing a constraint.

Comment: > untyped javascript code you may import. But what about untyped javascript that I've written in the past? It's not a library, just code that used to be JS that is now TS.